# Probability of two elements falling within a certain interval

Tags: probability-theory

> a, b are selected at random and 0 <= a <= 3 and -2 <= b <=0. What is the probability the distance between a and b is greater than 3.

I did this and said that $a$ must be in $(2, 3)$ and $b$ must be in $(-2, -1)$. Then the probability that $b$ is in that interval is $\frac{1}{2}$ and the probability that $a$ is in $(2, 3)$ is $\frac{1}{3}$. So the probability for both is $\frac{1}{3}$. Is that the right approach?

Comment: The answer is $1/3$.  Check your reasoning.  Don't forget that $a > b$ or $b > a$, in some cases.

Comment: @user85503 Please do not suggest edits erasing the mathematical content of a question.

Comment: @turkeyhundt Please do not approve edits erasing the mathematical content of a question.

Comment: @yoknapatawpha Please do not approve edits erasing the mathematical content of a question.

Answer (score 1):

I would think of it more like an area of probability.  I plotted $a$ on the x axis and $b$ on the y axis.  I drew a line where the difference between the two is 3.  Can you tell what area as a percentage of the whole area is what you are after?

[image]

Comment: I can do it after I have the picture, but how did you know that the line is there? Thank you

Comment: I just plugged in some points.  If $b=-2$ then $a$ must be greater than 1.  If $b=-1$ then $a$ can be anything greater than 2.  And if $b=0$, $a$ must be 3.  Looking at the line i was confident it was correct and then the final, simple step was to see which side of the line I was interested in.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you.

Comment: A good generalization of this problem:  A straight stick is broken at two points, randomly chosen uniformly along its length.  What is the probability that the resulting three pieces can form a triangle?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork "Generalization"?